# Directinput not detecting mouse buttons

Tags: directx, directx-9, directinput

I am using DirectInput in my game to handle input and everything was working fine in my previous PC. But I had to change my PC, my new PC is Dell Inspiron 3542 and Directinput is not detecting any mouse buttons in it.

Is it possible to solve this issue without attaching an external mouse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What OS did your 'previous PC' have vs. the 'new PC'? Note that use of DirectInput for mouse/keyboard is not recommended as its' all basically hacks on the existing Win32 system messages on Windows XP or later.

Comment: I was using Windows 8.1 in both PC's. What are my options instead of DirectInput. I think that XInput is only for controllers.

Comment: For keyboard/mouse, just use [``WM_MOUSE*``](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645533.aspx) and [``WM_KEY*``](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645530.aspx) Win32 messages to get the keyboard/mouse information. You'd use XInput for the Xbox Common Controller gamepads. If you need support for other controllers (HID joysticks, PS gamepad, etc.) then you'd use DirectInput.